# How to share an Anaconda Python environment between multiple users?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have Anaconda 5.1 Python distribution installed (by the system admin) on Windows 10, for all users. I can create an environment and then view the available environments:

```
λ conda create --name py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

...

```
λ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base    *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
py35       C:\Users\<my-user-name>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35
```

When I log in as a different user, however, only the `base` environment is visible/available. How can I create an environment and make it available to all users of the system?

The [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html) discusses multi-user installations, but I cannot see how to make environments available to other users.

Comment: this appears to be resolved as per issue located here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1329 , docs here: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/admin-multi-user-install.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key here is adding the path to the *folder containing the environment(s)* to the user's conda configuration file `.condarc`. Like this:

```
envs_dirs:
  - C:\full\path\to\environments\folder
```

This makes all the environments (subfolders within) available to the user. It does not appear to be possible to make a specific, named environment available.

As has been pointed out, you can create an environment in a specific location using the `-p` flag, and then add the parent directory to the configuration file, but this is not a requirement. This may be useful, however, to avoid permissions errors if sharing environments that exists in protected user areas.

On Windows 10, my user configuration file was in `C:\Users\<my-user-name>\`, and I just added the above text to the end of it.

Comment: At least for conda 4.5.11 installed on Ubuntu, adding "env_dirs:" to a `.condarc` in the miniconda install directory will allow users to create envs in the directories specified, but they still have to use the `--prefix` flag if they want to override the default conda install directory (usually in the user's home folder). The "home folder as default" doesn't work for my group, given that we have very limited file number limits in our home directories, and conda envs generate a bunch of files.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, although I had another person test and it still made the environment in their home .conda directory.  Any idea what could be causing this?  I deleted his local .condarc file (it was empty anyway), and it didn't help.

Answer (score 33):

I would shy away from sharing environments with other users, because if they don't know what they are doing, they could add packages that could conflict with other packages and/or even delete packages that another user might need. The preferred approach is that after you have created an environment, you export it as a yml file:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Then you send the users the yml file and have them build their own environment using the yml:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

If you really want to use a shared environment where every user can access, then you have to use the `-p` or `--prefix` option in your create:

```
conda create -p C:/full/public/path/to/py35 python=3.5
```

And then instruct your users to add the public path (`C:/full/public/path/to`) to their [conda config file](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs). Then, they should be able to see the environment when running `conda env list`.

Comment: I would suggest using the --no-builds flag.

Comment: I see that at the end of the exported env file there's also a line indicating the current env location: (`prefix: /home/someone/.conda/envs/env-name`). Can it be safely removed? Other users shouldn't be able to access that path anyway.

Comment: @NoamPeled `--no-builds` allows using different package builds in the new env. This can be useful when working on different OS'es where the same package builds are almost never available, but I don't see the point when the users are on the same OS?

Answer (score 3):

The Conda-Cheatseet [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) lists these following commands.

Save Environment:

```
conda list --explicit > my-env.txt
```

Create Environment:

```
conda env create --file my-env.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In case Linux user will be interested, I find a most easiest way to figure out this issue, as long as the other person open the corresponding permission to you, you can simply soft link it to your own env folder:

presuming you are using miniconda, soft link the other user's env folder (ex. Python312) to your own ~/miniconda3/envs

```
 cd ~/miniconda3/envs/
 ln -s /home/to/otheruser/miniconda3/envs/Python312 ./
```

that's it, you can find a new env by 'conda env list' without switching to other user or exporting path etc.

Answer (score 0):

1- If you want to add a directory to the environment directories you can use this command:

`conda config --add envs_dirs the/path/to/my/env`

You need to replace "the/path/to/my/env" with the full path to the env folder. For example, if I want to add the following path to environment directories

`D:\Anaconda3\envs`

I'll execute

`conda config --add envs_dirs D:\Anaconda3\envs`

To see the list of all environment directories (and other configs) you can run this:

`conda config --show`

2- A **better** way to do this is to create the environment in a directory accessible to all users. To do that you can create the Conda env using "--prefix" or "-p" like the following command:

`conda create --prefix the/path/to/my/env`

For activation:

`conda activate the/path/to/my/env`

For example:

`conda create --prefix "D:/Shared_Conda_Env"`

which can be activated by all users using

`conda activate "D:/Shared_Conda_Env"`